# Build PEM file by having ec public key coordinates

Tags: elliptic-curve

I try to create an elliptic public key by calculate the point on curve from a given number ( my private key ), so I have the coordinates `(x,y)` of elliptic curve point

I get the coordinates by

```
myPublicKeyCoordinates = myPrivateKeyValue * GPointOnCurve
```

How can i build the `PEM` ( or `DER` ) file for my public key?

I don't care about language (`java, python, javascript, ...`) 
because i want to known how build the file ( even if i write every single byte... )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you already know about [ITU-T X.680-201508](https://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-X.680-201508-I!!PDF-E&type=items) (the ASN.1 language) and [ITU-T X.690-201508](https://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-X.690-201508-I!!PDF-E&type=items) (the BER (and CER) and DER encodings for ASN.1 data), the main defining document for Elliptic Curve Keys and their representation is https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf from the Standards for Efficient Cryptography Group (not the US Securites and Exchange Commission).

Section C.3 (Syntax for Elliptic Curve Public Keys) says that the general transport container for an EC public key is the X.509 SubjectPublicKeyInfo structure:

```
SubjectPublicKeyInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
    algorithm AlgorithmIdentifier {{ECPKAlgorithms}} (WITH COMPONENTS
        {algorithm, parameters}) ,
    subjectPublicKey BIT STRING
}
```

The possible "algorithms" (which really means key encoding types) is the open-ended set

```
ECPKAlgorithms ALGORITHM ::= {
    ecPublicKeyType |
    ecPublicKeyTypeRestricted |
    ecPublicKeyTypeSupplemented |
    {OID ecdh PARMS ECDomainParameters {{SECGCurveNames}}} |
    {OID ecmqv PARMS ECDomainParameters {{SECGCurveNames}}},
    ...
}

ecPublicKeyType ALGORITHM ::= {
    OID id-ecPublicKey PARMS ECDomainParameters {{SECGCurveNames}}
}

...
```

ECDomainParameters came from C.2:

```
ECDomainParameters{ECDOMAIN:IOSet} ::= CHOICE {
    specified SpecifiedECDomain,
    named ECDOMAIN.&id({IOSet}),
    implicitCA NULL
}
```

C.3 mentions about halfway through

> The elliptic curve public key (a value of type ECPoint that is an OCTET STRING) is mapped to a subjectPublicKey (a value encoded as type BIT STRING) as follows: The most significant bit of the value of the OCTET STRING becomes the most significant bit of the value of the BIT STRING and so on with consecutive bits until the least significant bit of the OCTET STRING becomes the least significant bit of the BIT STRING.

So we seek backwards and find

> An elliptic curve point itself is represented by the following type
>
> ```
> ECPoint ::= OCTET STRING
> ```
>
> whose value is the octet string obtained from the conversion routines given in Section 2.3.3.

2.3.3 (Elliptic-Curve-Point-to-Octet-String Conversion) has a lot of words, but the best supported format is not using point compression (and P != the point at infinity)

> 3. If P = (xP , yP ) != O and point compression is not being used, proceed as follows:
>
> 3.1. Convert the field element xP to an octet string X of length (log2 q)/8 octets using the conversion routine specified in Section 2.3.5.
>
> 3.2. Convert the field element yP to an octet string Y of length (log2 q)/8 octets using the conversion routine specified in Section 2.3.5.
>
> 3.3. Output M = 04<sub>16</sub> || X || Y .

2.3.5 is a whole lot of words for "big endian byte order of a length long enough to hold all values in the field" (aka "leave in leading zeros").

So now we party.

Given the FIPS 186-3 reference key on secp256r1 (`d=70A12C2DB16845ED56FF68CFC21A472B3F04D7D6851BF6349F2D7D5B3452B38A`),

Q is
(`8101ECE47464A6EAD70CF69A6E2BD3D88691A3262D22CBA4F7635EAFF26680A8`, `D8A12BA61D599235F67D9CB4D58F1783D3CA43E78F0A5ABAA624079936C0C3A9`)

And the public key DER looks like

```
// SubjectPublicKeyInfo
30 XA
   // AlgorithmIdentifier
   30 XB
      // AlgorithmIdentifier.id (id-ecPublicKey (1.2.840.10045.2.1))
      06 07 2A 86 48 CE 3D 02 01
      // AlgorithmIdentifier.parameters, using the named curve id (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)
      06 08 2A 86 48 CE 3D 03 01 07
   // SubjectPublicKeyInfo.subjectPublicKey
   03 XC 00
      // Uncompressed public key
      04
      // Q.X
      81 01 EC E4 74 64 A6 EA D7 0C F6 9A 6E 2B D3 D8
      86 91 A3 26 2D 22 CB A4 F7 63 5E AF F2 66 80 A8
      // Q.Y
      D8 A1 2B A6 1D 59 92 35 F6 7D 9C B4 D5 8F 17 83
      D3 CA 43 E7 8F 0A 5A BA A6 24 07 99 36 C0 C3 A9
```

Count up all the bytes for XA, XB, and XC:

XC = 32 (Q.X) + 32 (Q.Y) + 1 (0x04) + 1 (0x00 for the unused bits) = 66 = 0x42

XB = 19 = 0x13

XA is then 66 + 19 + 2 (tag bytes) + 2 (length bytes) = 89 = 0x59

(And, of course, if any of our length values exceeded 0x7F we would have had to encode them correctly)

So now we are left with

```
30 59 30 13 06 07 2A 86 48 CE 3D 02 01 06 08 2A
86 48 CE 3D 03 01 07 03 42 00 04 81 01 EC E4 74
64 A6 EA D7 0C F6 9A 6E 2B D3 D8 86 91 A3 26 2D
22 CB A4 F7 63 5E AF F2 66 80 A8 D8 A1 2B A6 1D
59 92 35 F6 7D 9C B4 D5 8F 17 83 D3 CA 43 E7 8F
0A 5A BA A6 24 07 99 36 C0 C3 A9
```

And, we verify:

```
$ xxd -r -p | openssl ec -text -noout -inform der -pubin
read EC key
<paste, then hit CTRL+D>
30 59 30 13 06 07 2A 86 48 CE 3D 02 01 06 08 2A
86 48 CE 3D 03 01 07 03 42 00 04 81 01 EC E4 74
64 A6 EA D7 0C F6 9A 6E 2B D3 D8 86 91 A3 26 2D
22 CB A4 F7 63 5E AF F2 66 80 A8 D8 A1 2B A6 1D
59 92 35 F6 7D 9C B4 D5 8F 17 83 D3 CA 43 E7 8F
0A 5A BA A6 24 07 99 36 C0 C3 A9
Private-Key: (256 bit)
pub:
    04:81:01:ec:e4:74:64:a6:ea:d7:0c:f6:9a:6e:2b:
    d3:d8:86:91:a3:26:2d:22:cb:a4:f7:63:5e:af:f2:
    66:80:a8:d8:a1:2b:a6:1d:59:92:35:f6:7d:9c:b4:
    d5:8f:17:83:d3:ca:43:e7:8f:0a:5a:ba:a6:24:07:
    99:36:c0:c3:a9
ASN1 OID: prime256v1
NIST CURVE: P-256
```

Printing it as "Private-Key: (256-bit)" is just a bug/quirk of the tool, there's no private key there.

Things are harder for specified parameter curves, but those don't interoperate well (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5480#section-2.1.1 says that a conforming CA MUST NOT use the specified parameter form, or the implicit form, but MUST use the named form).